# Using activity objects in Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

(I'm unsure if I am doing this correctly.)
I am creating a simple timetable app which has a main timetable activity with five buttons to five different days. When a button is clicked I want to start an activity that uses a base activity that takes in two int arrays which are just the codes of lessons to pass to a data class. How do I use this base class to create multiple different activities using intents when a button is clicked?

Timetable Activity (Simplified)-intent code not working.

```
public class TimetableActivity extends Activity {
private Button monABut;

int[] monAlessons = {5,2,6,5,5};
int[] monAteachers = {0,2,7,1,0};

public DayAOneActivity mondayA = new DayAOneActivity(monAlessons,monAteachers);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetable);

    monABut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.monAButton);
    monABut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mondayA);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}}
```

Day activity constructor

```
public class DayAOneActivity extends Activity {

int[] lessonCodes;
int[] teacherCodes;

public DayAOneActivity(int[] lessonCode, int[] teacherCode){
    this.lessonCodes = lessonCode;
    this.teacherCodes = teacherCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to start activity is to use it's class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(TimetableActivity.this, DayAOneActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Activity object itself is created by Android framework automatically